# SQL join for 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to join 5 tables, my query is:

```
 SELECT maingenre.MainGenreId,maingenre.Name AS mname,'saewill.mp3' AS mp3,releaseprod.ArtistId,r me
FROM maingasdsadenre 
LEFT JOIN releasaddsaseprod ON maidssadngenre.MainGenreId = dd.a
LEFT JOIN artist ON d.ArtistId = d.ArtistId
l
```

It is not giving me an accurate result.
I have this error:

```
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'releaseprod'
```

Answer (score 1):

if your join always on `releaseprod` try this

```
 SELECT maingenere.MainGenreId,
          maingenere.Name AS mname,
          'saewill.mp3'   AS mp3,
          releaseprod.ArtistId,
          releaseprod.MainGenreId,
          releaseprod.LabelId,
          artist.ArtistId,
          artist.Name AS aname,
          song.ArtistId,
          song.Name AS sname,
          song.Version,
          label.LabelId,
          label.Name AS lname
        FROM maingenere
        LEFT JOIN releaseprod
        ON ( maingenere.MainGenreId = releaseprod.MainGenreId
        AND artist.ArtistId         = releaseprod.ArtistId
        AND ong.ArtistId            = releaseprod.ArtistId
        AND label.LabelId           = releaseprod.LabelI )
```

or

edit your question and tell me to edit my response

or may be you mean this

```
SELECT maingenere.MainGenreId,
  maingenere.Name AS mname,
  'saewill.mp3'   AS mp3,
  releaseprod.ArtistId,
  releaseprod.MainGenreId,
  releaseprod.LabelId,
  artist.ArtistId,
  artist.Name AS aname,
  song.ArtistId,
  song.Name AS sname,
  song.Version,
  label.LabelId,
  label.Name AS lname
FROM maingenere 
LEFT JOIN releaseprod
ON (maingenere.MainGenreId = releaseprod.MainGenreId)
LEFT JOIN artist
ON (artist.ArtistId = releaseprod.ArtistId)
LEFT JOIN song
ON (song.ArtistId = releaseprod.ArtistId)
LEFT JOIN label
ON( label.LabelId = releaseprod.LabelId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
SELECT maingenere.MainGenreId,maingenere.Name as mname,'saewill.mp3' as mp3,
       releaseprod.ArtistId,releaseprod.MainGenreId,releaseprod.LabelId,artist.ArtistId,
       artist.Name as aname,song.ArtistId,song.Name as sname,song.Version,label.LabelId,
       label.Name as lname
FROM maingenere 
left join releaseprod ON maingenere.MainGenreId = releaseprod.MainGenreId 
left join artist ON artist.ArtistId = releaseprod.ArtistId
left join song ON song.ArtistId = releaseprod.ArtistId
left join label ON label.LabelId = releaseprod.LabelId;
```